# Way to get un-cropped thumbnail images?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can anyone advise if / how to get un-cropped thumbnail images of files in drive?

Thumbnails in the Recent files component appear to be un-cropped (if you use browser inspector), whereas thumbnails in the component below it are below are cropped. While you can change the size of the thumbnail in its url query params, this doesnt solve the cropping problem.

Im building a redesigned frontend - using css grid for a more irregular aesthetic - as a learning project. To do this, Id need to get un-cropped images - to, for example, show documents as vertical rectangles, not the standard square cropped thumbnail. Id appreciate it if you have any ideas on this. Thanks!